# How to calculate a mean on a datable in R based on several conditions

Tags: r, data.table, data-manipulation

I have data like the following :

```
library(lubridate)
library(dplyr)
library(data.table)
MWE <- data.table(
  Date=rep(seq(ymd("2020-1-1"), ymd("2020-3-30"), by = "days"),each=6),
  Country=rep(c("France","United States","Germany"),90*6),
  TransportType=rep(c("Train","Cars"),each=3,90*3),
  Value=rnorm(90*6,2,3)
  )
```

I want to create a new variable, that is the mean of value :

- By Country and Transport
- By weekday
- based on dates before March (but here for March too)

So the mean should be calculated on January and February, but in the database for the whole period.

I have managed to do the first two (or I think so, I am checking) :

```
MWE_2 <- MWE %>%
  .[,JourSem:=weekdays(Date)] %>%
  .[,Moyenne:=mean(Value),by=.(Country,JourSem,TransportType)]
```

But I am unsure how to pass another condition in that. I think I get it form this

```
MWE_3 <- MWE %>%
  .[,JourSem:=weekdays(Date)] %>%
  .[Date <= "2020-02-29",Moyenne:=mean(Value),by=.(Country,JourSem,TransportType)]
```

But I lack the value for March dates, which is logical, as they are filtered out, which is therefore not what I want.

Answer (score 1):

We can first calculate mean for January and February month for each weekday and then join this data with March data.

```
library(data.table)

MWE[, JourSem:=weekdays(Date)]

d1 <- MWE[Date <= as.Date("2020-02-29")] %>%
        .[, .(Moyenne = mean(Value)), JourSem]

MWE[Date > as.Date("2020-02-29")][d1, on = 'JourSem']
```

Comment: I have been unclear. I want the mean to span other March data, but to be calculated only on January and February

Comment: I am not clear about what value you want to show in March? Do you mean March data will have mean values of the entire data (January and February combined) ? So entire March will have the same value?

Comment: I want, for instance for data on a wednesday of March in Germany about trains, to have the average of values of wednesdays in Germany about trains, calculated on January and February (which would then by construction to be the same as the one on each wednesdsay in Germany for trains for the whole period)

Comment: Can you check if the updated answer is closer to what you want? `d1` is the data with mean for each weekday in Jan and Feb.

Comment: It is, alhgouth I was hoping not to have to slice the data to get it